# acceptverbs httpverbs.get?

Tags: http-verbs

What is the use of it????
 acceptverbs(httpverbs.get)
and explain about the httpverbs.post too..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applied to an action, it restricts the action to only requests made with that particular HTTP verb, i.e., `GET` or `POST`.  Even if a different type of request than specified comes in that would match based on the name and signature, it won't match because the request type is not allowed.